# Is using Ajax auto partial reload too heavy for chat purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to make a chat application with [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) and [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). I made it reload partially every five seconds so that users can see new messages, and I have tons of chat rooms.

Is it too heavy to the server? Or this is supposed to be normal thing?

Please imagine if there were 20 chat rooms each with 10 users. 200 people are reloading every five seconds with an Ajax request. Is it too heavy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ajax loading chat is not the best way to implement a chat, because with the time and users you will be facing loading issues, one way of doing this would be web sokets.

Or I found this [pusher](http://pusher.com/) service and it seems it gives an easy solution, although it's not free. I think their free plan is enough to start off. When you have users, you could go for their paying plans.

But please note, I havent tried this :D

Comment: what do you mean? What's the loading issues?

Comment: I had this issue long time back, when there are many ajax requests with in short about of times, when the number of requests goes up, there were javascript errors and hence it break the Ajax (DOM) and case the entire system to stuck

Answer (score 3):

I like to avoid timeouts and intervarls when possible, so I suggest you to take a look at [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

I would also like to point out, that in your case [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) could be not so heavy, because you do not have so many users, but if you really will go for Ajax, be sure to have a good request structure and do not allow users to post every millisecond, so add appropiate controls :)